# Regarding XML to CSV conversion in python query

Tags: python, xml, csv

Its great pleasure to meet you via this platform.. As beginner, I have question. Here, I have sample XML document. I have to convert it to csv form from xml form.

```
<message>
<mail>raj@gmail.com</mail>
<address>
<houseno> 123 </houseno>
</address>
</message>

<message>
<mail>raj@gmail.com</mail>
<contact> 23278378</contact>
<address>
<houseno> 123 </houseno>
</address>
</message>

<message>
<mail>raj@gmail.com</mail>
<address>
<houseno> 123 </houseno>
</address>
<place> Mumbai </place>
</message>
```

In above xml , I want to access mail , contact address and place and stored in csv file.. There are no common tags in message tag in this document. hence I am unable to access it.. Kindly help me how can I do it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to install and use [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup). This can locate all of the `message` entries. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

xml = """<message>
<mail>raj@gmail.com</mail>
<address>
<houseno> 123 </houseno>
</address>
</message>

<message>
<mail>raj@gmail.com</mail>
<contact> 23278378</contact>
<address>
<houseno> 123 </houseno>
</address>
</message>

<message>
<mail>raj@gmail.com</mail>
<address>
<houseno> 123 </houseno>
</address>
<place> Mumbai </place>
</message>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "html.parser")

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Mail', 'Address', 'Place'])
    
    for message in soup.find_all('message'):
        mail = message.mail.text
        address = message.address.houseno.get_text(strip=True)
        place = message.place.get_text(strip=True) if message.place else ''
        csv_output.writerow([mail, address, place])
```

This would create a CSV output file as:

```
Mail,Address,Place
raj@gmail.com,123,
raj@gmail.com,123,
raj@gmail.com,123,Mumbai
```

Comment: Nice sir...Its really good package for malformed html or xml tags... Thank you so much